# How to copy table to Excel or Google Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, html, excel, google-sheets, html-table

I want to implement a simple way of copying table to clipboard and pasting it to Excel or Google spreadsheet. The only problem is that if row starts with empty cell then all data will be shifted to the left after pasting it.

There're few hacks to make table pretty such as using `&nbsp;` in empty cells. The following method won't work as it will be pasted to Excel as well.

Is there a solution?

Consider the following code:

```
<table border="1"">
<tr>
  <td>Jill</td>
  <td>Smith</td>        
  <td>50</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>     
  <td>94</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: "I want to implement a simple way of copying table to clipboard"  From where? In what language do you want to implement this?  Your question is a bit vague, so you might want to expand a little.

Comment: Javascript. As a solution could be opening a popup with code selected. But I'd love to know how to ctr+c - ctr+v such table.

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine when copying from the displayed HTML in Chrome into Excel. 
Check your Paste Options in Excel.